# Find and replace value between two tables column with different datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have tow tables in sql server 2008

```
TBL_CustomerMaster
[FilingId] [numeric]  (18, 0) NOT NULL,
[CustId]   [nvarchar] (500)   COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,

TBL_Customer
[FilingId]  [numeric]  (18, 0) NOT NULL,
[CustUnqId] [numeric]  (18, 0) NOT NULL,
[CustId]    [nvarchar] (500)   COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
```

I used bulk insert to load data into two tables for each FilingId, CustId's for two tables are same. I have generated unique CustUnqId for TBL_Customer

Now i want to map the CustUnqId with CustId of TBL_CustomerMaster
i. e. replace CustId in TBL_CustomerMaster with corresponding CustUnqId form TBL_Customer

kindly suggest the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, but enclose this into transaction and do the testing before putting anything into production environment:

```
SELECT  a.CustId,
        b.CustUnqId
INTO    #temp
FROM    TBL_CustomerMaster a
JOIN    TBL_Customer b ON
        a.CustId = b.CustId

UPDATE  TBL_CustomerMaster
SET     CustId = t.CustUnqId
FROM    TBL_CustomerMaster a
JOIN    #temp t ON
        t.CustId = a.CustId
```

Comment: Thanx Ivan. I am new to sql i dont no about temp table. Shall i have to drop the temp table after updation of CustUnqId. can you suggest anything for getting started with temp tables in sql server.

Comment: You're welcome, temporary tables are automatically dropped when your connection to the SQL Server is closed, or if they are inside of a stored procedure they are dropped when the procedure exits. If you want to run query repeatedly in SSMS window and it uses temp tables you might have to drop the table explicitly (`DROP TABLE #temp`) or the server will tell you that table with same name already exists. Alternative to temporary tables are table variables, they might have a very different performance impact. CTE could also be used for this example. You'll find many good tutorials on web. Cheers!